# How do I efficiently persist checkbox selections, in a java web app with front controller pattern?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, session, cookies

There are several questions and answers about persisting checkbox selections when leaving or updating a web page, but the majority of them are a lot more complicated to execute, considering the code structure of my web app.

**What I got:**

- A Java web application, that follows the front controller pattern. All URL's are intercepted by the front controller, which in turn finds a relevant action based on a strategy pattern, and executes an update, before redirecting to a new page, or the old one.
- One of a handful pages got three categories of checkboxes, which toggles visibility of page elements. each category has about 4-6 single checkboxes.

**What I Need:**

- An efficient way to persist the users selected checkboxes, when navigating away from the site. Wether it is cookies or sessions is arbitrary. It does not really matter if the data is saved for a short or a long period of time, but at least for each session.

**What I've tried:**

- Basic tutorials with Ajax, to send updates on every change of a checkbox. However, they base themselves upon communicating with their own servlet, which is not compliant with the Front Controller pattern ideology that intercepts all URL's.
- Cookies. However I do not know the scope of a cookie, or how I should use them. IE if i should use one cookie for the entire selection, or one cookie for each category of checkboxes.
- Directly setting a session variable in Javascript, which is not possible due to the server-side/client-side conflict.
- Sending an individual call to the front controller servlet every time a checkbox changes, which works, but might result in a vast number of server calls, which I think is unnecessary.

I have a feeling that Ajax is the way to go here, but all solutions that are more efficient than my current working solution are very welcome. I am sorry that I cannot post any sample code, due to the fact that the webapp is being developed on my localhost, and cannot be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a javascript function which is toggled upon a 'click' of one of three checkboxes? This javascript function could then in turn do a GET or POST request to your controller.

Comment: Yes i could. :). But is that really efficient? As stated in my question, this will lead to a lot of server requests.

Comment: I see, sorry I had misread that. I think with Ajax you would get as much server requests, as it still has to talk to your server

Comment: yeah, it seems like a cookie solution might be the best. I am working on it now.